# "gcloud app deploy" skips my imported files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-sdk

This is my first time using Google cloud with python sdk. I'm able to make a simple webpage and take users input and it works fine. But I want the user's input to be passed to a different python file that I have made for an analysis. When I try to import the file it fails, and the gcloud log file makes it clear that the reason is that gcloud is skipping the upload of the custom python files I have created. I cannot understand why it is skipping the files, however. My understanding is that there are two ways that files might be skipped:

1. The file might match the exclusion regular expressions. However this is not the case for my files, and the gcloud log file confirms this.
2. Files under the "skip_files" specification in the app.yaml file can be skipped. However I never made any such specification.

Is there any other way that files might be skipped in an upload or any way that I can force them to be included?

Thank you very much!